# How to form this sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT state,count(*) as regular 
FROM X 
group by state
```

This gives a result like

```
AL 10
AK 20 
AZ 25

SELECT state,count(*) as regular 
FROM X 
where alcohol_use=TRUE 
group by state
```

This gives a result like

```
AL 5
AK 10
AZ 20
```

I need a single query which finds out the percentage and provides me an output like

```
AL 50%
AK 50%
AZ 80%
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT state,
         SUM(alcohol_use=TRUE) / COUNT(*) * 100
    FROM X
GROUP BY state
```

`SUM(alcohol_use=TRUE)` expression would add up values of `alcohol_use=TRUE` which is either `true` or `false` which is then implicitly casted to `1` or `0` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this "partial count" is to sum a `case` expression with your condition. E.g.:

```
SELECT   state, 
         SUM (CASE alcohol_use WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) as percent
FROM     x
GROUP BY state
```